# Cannot get data from nasdaq site

Tags: python

My code below download the website https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/mrtn/earnings . I am interested in data in tables, say "Quarterly Earnings Surprise Amount" Table. From developer tool on Chrome, I can see the data is in tags such as:
`<td class="earnings-forecast__cell">1.13</td>`
But when using the code below to download, the number in tag is disappear. Only have `<td class="earnings-forecast__cell"> </td>`

Can you please help to fix? Thanks, HHC

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

header = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
  'referer': 'https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/mrtn/earnings'
  
}
# Send a get request to server:
url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/mrtn/earnings'
html = requests.get(url=url,headers=header)
# check if request is received
html.status_code  #Successful responses (200–299)

data=soup(html.content,'lxml')
print(type(data))
# print(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try looking at the page source, you can identify that the table you are interested doesn't have any values. This indicates that the data in the table is rendered via JavaScript.

On checking the sources and the requests sent from the browser's "Network" tab, we can see that a xhr request from a JS script is sent and replied back with the data that you are looking for. The endpoint to which the script sent out a request is: `https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/MRTN/earnings-surprise`.

Try this,

```
import requests

header = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
    'referer': 'https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/mrtn/earnings'
}

url = 'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/MRTN/earnings-surprise'
response = requests.get(url = url, headers = header)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.json())
else:
    print("Failed", response.status_code)
```

If you use Chrome, filter requests to "Fetch/XHR", and you should be able to view the request. (Refresh the page once with the "Network" tab open)

[image: Networks tab]

Happy coding!

Comment: I click on Network tab , I see it has column "Name|Status|Type|... Waterfall" but there is no information there. How can you find this ```https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/MRTN/earnings-surprise``` ?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Refresh the page once with the "Network" tab open to see the requests going though. I filtered it to "Fetch/XHR" because that was the data you were interested (some request that is responded with your data).

Comment: I followed your instruction and able to get everything in that site BUT fail to get ONLY 1 thing, which is "Yearly Earnings Forecast" table. Any trick to find where it is? Thanks

Comment: https://api.nasdaq.com/api/analyst/MRTN/earnings-forecast/ <- A call to this endpoint responds with the info you need.